# How to enforce Webpack to detect and recompile only files that were changed?

Tags: node.js, webpack

Is there (and should) be a way to tell Webpack to recompile just those changed that were made?

Webpack needs to recompile just the element that was added.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

For live reloading there is e.g. `webpack-dev-server`

For improving build speed, take look at https://webpack.js.org/configuration/cache to cache certain information on disk.